# Opposite of "Native english speaker"

Tags: synonyms

How to talk about people whose mother tongue isn't English? Is there an equivalent of the French expressions "*non-francophone*" or "*non-anglophone*"?

Comment: A "non-native English speaker". As opposed to a "native English speaker".

Comment: @Laure I can't tell for sure, but I feel OP expected something shorter... I'd like to learn shorter form too, if it exists :)

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ: the word ["anglophone"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anglophone) exists but it's more usual to say native/non-native. "English speaker" is not necessary if it is obvious from context that English is the language under discussion.

Comment: Well, some people might say **English language learner** :-)  Or just **learner**.

Comment: @snailplane: I appreciate the pun, but the implication that anyone whose first language wasn't English will forever be a learner I can only accept in the sense that _everybody_ keeps learning their whole life. And in that case, there is no distinction between native and non-native speakers anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, it is as simple as saying someone is a "non-native English speaker," or saying that English is not their primary language. Sometimes they are called ESL-Learners, which means "English as a Second Language Learners."

There is not really a name or term for people whose primary language is not English; you basically just say they do not speak English as their first language.